# What is a car's “interior packaging?”

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is a car's *interior packaging*?

This is from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_%28automobile%29) article on Crossovers:

> Using the unibody construction typical of passenger vehicles, the crossover combines SUV design features such as tall **interior packaging**, high H-point seating, high ground-clearance or all-wheel-drive capability — with design features from an automobile such as a passenger vehicle's platform, independent rear suspension, car-like handling and fuel economy.

Comment: My guess is it's "motoring correspondent's jargon" for the fact that the passenger compartment is relatively tall (a common characteristic of SUV vehicles). Meaning to say even a tall adult can sit up straight without their head squashing against the roof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a [Society of Automobile Engineers](http://www.sae.org/pdevent/C0108):

> One of the most important aspects in the design of the vehicle is in creating an interior compartment that accommodates the needs of the customer base. Occupant and **interior packaging** involves: determining the necessary amount of vehicle interior space for the customer, arranging interior and structural components in order to enhance the performance of the customer, and increasing overall satisfaction, comfort, accommodation and safety for all occupants. The occupant and **interior packaging** process relies on the sciences of human factors and ergonomics in order to design for the customer.

*Tall interior packaging* would be the result of raising the roof-line by lengthening or changing the angle of various structural components like pillars.

Comment: And to learn more, the seminar only costs $1200.